# Plot changes after the creation of an other figure with same code

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, the weirdest thing happens to me. I create two bar charts from a data set using:

```
plotX <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x=factor(someVariable), y=var2, fill=factor(var3)+ 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
plotX
plotY <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x=factor(someVariable), y=var2, fill=factor(var3)+ 
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
plotY
plotX
```

when I look at the first, everything is fine, I create the second, everything is fine. I look at the first again and the last two bars are switched XD
How does the creation of a plot influence another plot that is "savely" saved as a variable?

Cheers, Mascha

Comment: Provide example data, so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: You're missing two additional closing brackets `))` before each `+`.